# Hyperbolic geometry - image of horoball

Tags: hyperbolic-geometry, conformal-geometry, mobius-transformation

This is a pretty basic question I suppose, but I want to check my intuition in hyperbolic geometry which is a field I've just started studying.

Let $A$ be a horoball in the hyperbolic disc $B^N$($=\mathbb{H}^N$), with tangent point $p\in S^N$.
let $g$ be a conformal (i.e. oriention preserving) isometry of $B^N$.

I know that $g$ transforms hyperbolic balls to hyperbolic balls.

1. From that I believe I can deduce that $g$ also transforms horoballs to horoballs, right? Because horoball is after all a euclidean ball and therefore a hyperbolic ball.
2. In particular, if $g(p)=p$ then $g(A)=A$, right?
3. In the latter case, my intuition says that $g$ must be some sort of clockwise or anti-clockwise rotation towards the base point $p$. This is not very clear to me in that multidimensional case.
   For simplicity I am thinking of $\mathbb D=\mathbb B^2$ and a horoball at $(1,0)$ which is just a circle tangent at the point $(1,0)$. So I'm thinking that $g$ must be some flow in the direction of this cicle (just moving each point in the clockwise direction, each point in the correct amount so the orientation would be preserved). in particular $|g(x)|=|g^{-1}(x)|$ for $x$ the antipodal point to $(1,0)$ on this horocicle. Is this true at all?

Comment: easier to do this in the upper half plane model (with a point at infinity), orientation preserving isometries  are Mobius transformations with real coefficients and positive determinant

Comment: @WillJagy ya, I've tried to alternate between the two and answer my question in either model. It didn't work in neither.

Comment: Any such transformation can be made up from composing three simple types: mutiply by a positive real, or add a real, or map by $-1/z.$ This is just taking the 2 by 2 matrix to the identity by elementary row transformations, and the fact that composition of Mobius transformations agrees with multiplication of the matrices

Comment: This is a nice decomposition. Kinda what i'm looking for. I'll think a bit about how to translate this into answers, wounder if I can.

Comment: Your item 1 reveals that you have a misconception about the relationship between hyperbolic balls and Euclidean balls in $B^N$. What is true is that a *closed* hyperbolic ball in $B^N$ is the same as a *closed* Euclidean ball contained in $B^N$. A horoball is not a closed Euclidean ball contained in $B^N$. Instead, a horoball is the *intersection with $B^N$* of a closed Euclidean ball which is contained $B^N \cup S^{N-1} = \text{closure}(B^N)$ and which intersects $S^{N-1}$ tangentially at a single point.

Comment: @LeeMosher Thank you for the comment. To be honest, all you have said  I do understand and know, so I don't think I have a misconception here. I just thought that it might be extended to horoballs, is it not?

Comment: @WillJagy any further more detailed assistance would be most appreciated, if possible!

Comment: What I meant is that your item 1 is a misconception on how to *prove* that $g$ transforms each horoball to a horoball. The proof is invalid because a horoball is not a hyperbolic ball. See my answer for a full proof.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I'm going to give an intrinsic/synthetic answer this question, i.e. an answer that not depend on any model of $\mathbb{H}^n$ (such as the upper half space model), but which instead uses only the intrinsic metric properties of $\mathbb{H}^n$.

Balls and horoballs in $\mathbb{H}^n$ each may be characterized by a metrically invariant property.

For balls, the metrically invariant property is simply the definition: $B \subset \mathbb{H}^n$ is a ball if and only if there exists $p \in \mathbb{H}^n$ and $r > 0$ such that 
$$B = \{q \in \mathbb{H}^n \,\bigm|\, d(p,q) \le r\}
$$
This ball $B$ is denoted $B(q,r)$. (I'm doing closed balls, of course). From the fact that this definition is evidently invariant under isometries, it follows that if $B$ is a ball and $g$ is an isometry then $g(B)$ is a ball.

So far, so good.

In order to characterize horoballs by a metrically invariant property, we will need to use the above characterization of balls, but we'll need one more preliminary thing, namely a metrically invariant property that characterizes rays: a subset $R \subset \mathbb{H}^n$ is a ray if and only if there exists a finite geodesic segment $[a,b] \subset \mathbb{H}^n$ such that $R$ is the union of all finite geodesic segments $[a,c]$ such that $[a,b] \subset [a,c]$. This ray $R$ will be denoted $\vec{ab}$.

Now we're ready for the metrically invariant property that characterizes horoballs: a subset $H \subset \mathbb{H}^n$ is a horoball if and only if there exists a ray $\vec{ab}$ such that $H$ is the closure of the union of all balls $B = B(q,r)$ such that $q \in \vec{ab} - \{a\}$ and $r = d(a,q)$.

To summarize, since horoballs are characterized by a metrically invariant property, for every horoball $H$ and every isometry $g$ the image $g(H)$ is also a horoball.

Comment: I played around a bit with your definition of a horoball but to my untrained eyes it doesn't seem to be correct, I played it out in the poincare halfplane model with $ a = (0,1) , q= (0,k), k > 1 $  but then the points $p: d_h(a,p) = d_h(q,p)$ where $d_h(i,j)$ is the hyperbolic distance between $i$ and $j$ are not on a horocycle (the line y=1) but all points are above this line.(inside the horocycle)

Comment: That's why I said to take the closure. The union of the balls $B(q,r)$ such that $q \in \vec{ab}-{a}$ with $r=d(a,q)$ is an open horoball. Its closure is a closed horoball which is what $H$ denotes. The closed horoball $H$ minus the open horoball is the horocycle.

Comment: Thanks I realised I made a mistake on my comment sorry

Answer (score 0):

Better say "center" than "origin".

$1.$ Yes and the action is transitive.

$2/3.$ For example, what happens if $p=\infty$ and $g(z)=z+i$?

Comment: 0. I actually ment tangent point. fixed it.
1. cool
2. Ya, this is a good point. it would simply give instead of a hyperplane $x_n=c$ the hyperplance $x_n=c+1$

Comment: Is it only $\infty$ that is giving this behavior or other points can do such thing?

Comment: The action on the boundary is also transitive.

Comment: I don't follow, how does it answer this?

Comment: You can first apply an isometry that takes a point in the boundary to any other that you want (in the boundary). After that you just need to conjugate the maps.

Comment: Thanks! Now as I try to understand deeper your example, how does it work for $\mathbb H^2$? aren't the mobious transformations are the ones with real coefficients?

Comment: Does it only work for $\mathbb H^3$, where the relevant maps are $SL(2,C)$?

Comment: You are right, I was thinking of $\mathbb H^3$, I should have made this clear.

Comment: I see!

Is there an example to convince me in other dimensions? cause when i'm thinking of $\mathbb H^2$ and for example $g(z)=z+1, p=\infty$ my claim in the original question does hold

Comment: And oh wait, if we are working in $\mathbb H^3$ then $g(z)=z+i$ isn't going upwards but to one of the sides, and in that case it does hold as well, isn't it?